# No se muestran los datos en un grafo dirigido PHP y JS

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un problema al mostrar un grafo dirigido resulta que no se o no puedo llamar el vector que el usuario esta generando por medio de un TXT

Este es el codigo con el cual estoy generando el grafo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    //crear un array con los nodos 
    var nodos = new vis.DataSet([
       <?php
       
       $N1 -> $_SESSION['getVectorV'];
        for ($i=1; $i<= $N1; $i++){
            if($i==$N1){
                echo "{id: $i, label: '$i'}";
            }else{
                echo "{id: $i, label: '$i'},";
           }
        };
        ?>]);

    // crear un array con las aristas 
     var aristas = new vis.DataSet([     
       <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=$_SESSION['grafo']->getMatrizA(); $i++){
           
            if($i==$_SESSION['grafo']->getMatrizA()){
                echo "{from: $i, to: $i}";
            }else{
                echo "{from: $i, to: $i},";
            } 
       };
        ?>]);
    
    
    // crear el grafo
    var contenedor = document.getElementById('grafo1');

// construir los datos
var datos = {
    nodes: nodos,
    edges: aristas
};

var opciones = {edges: {
        arrows: {
              to:     {enabled: true}
            }
    }};

// inicializar vista de grafo
var grafo = new vis.Network(contenedor, datos, opciones);



</script>
```

Segun las pruebas que llevo haciendo el error esta en el llamar al vector que anterior mente fue generado

Codigo de cuando el vector es generado y almacenado:

```
     if (isset($_POST["Idvertice"])){
          // $n->agregarVertice(new Vertice("a"));
            $AVertice = new Vertice($_POST["Idvertice"]);
            $_SESSION['grafo']->agregarVertice($AVertice);
         echo "Vertice Agregada!";
      }

echo "<b>Vector Vertices:</b><br>";
print_r($_SESSION['grafo']->getVectorV());
echo "<hr>";

    // Agregar Arista 
     if (isset($_POST["idverticeo"])){
            $_SESSION['grafo']->agregarArista( $_POST["idverticeo"],$_POST["idverticed"],$_POST["peso"]);
            echo "Arista Agregada!";
      }

echo "<b>Matriz Adyacencia:</b><br>";
print_r($_SESSION['grafo']->getMatrizA());
echo "<hr>";
```

Como se que si se esta almacenado el vector? sencillo

```
echo "<b>Vector Vertices:</b><br>";
print_r($_SESSION['grafo']->getVectorV());
echo "<hr>";
```

este codigo me muestra que el vector si tiene datos y me muestra cuales son

Muestro una imagen con datos agregados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, si se estan almacenando los datos ingresados por el usuario.

PERO, al momento de mostrar de manera GRAFICA, no funciona

el CONTENEDOR me sale en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora, si modifico la variable`$N1` y coloco un numero cualquiera, se muestra en la grafica, agreguemos el numero 5.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se generan 5 numeros, entonces lo que quiero es mostrar el vector que el usuario esta generando.

Codigo de los TXT:

```
Agregar Vertice:
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Id de Vertice: <input type="text" name="Idvertice">
<INPUT type="submit" value="Agregar">
</form>

Agregar Arista:
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Vertice Origen: <input type="text" name="idverticeo">
Vertice Destino: <input type="text" name="idverticed">
Peso: <input type="text" name="peso">
<INPUT type="submit" value="Agregar">
</form>
```

Comment: mmm armas el javascript con php ... y cual es el javascript resultante ... mejor dicho en la consola de javascript no te sale ningun error?

Comment: que hace new Vertice("A"), agregarVertice y agregarArista??

Comment: siento que a tu post le hace falta mas explicación y mas código

Comment: no sale ningun error en la  consola, publicare el codigo completo

Comment: metelo entre rtry catch no veo control de errores en ningun lado

Comment: igual no sale ninguno xd, eso o lo estoy metiendo mal

Comment: ni idea de que estas haciendo si no actualizas tu post

Comment: pero ya lo hice....

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso he actualiado la pregunta

Comment: entiendo que envías al PHP los datos del formulario y que el `php` genera un objeto que guarda en el array de `$_SESSION` del PHP `$_SESSION['grafo']->getVectorV()`... hasta este punto esta claro, pero mi pregunta es: como pasas el dato de PHP a javascript, por que el plugin de grafos entiendo que esta corriendo ya en javascript en ese momento?

Comment: aclaro tambien lo que imprimes con `print_r`: `$_SESSION['grafo']->getVectorV()` no es lo mismo que usas en el for de  `$N1 -> $_SESSION['getVectorV'];` esto ultimo no debería ser parecido a : `$N1 -> $_SESSION['grafo']->getVectorV();` o incluso debería ser: `$N1 -> $_SESSION['grafo']['getVectorV'];`

Comment: incluso creo que debe ser: `$N1 = $_SESSION['grafo']['getVectorV'];` o `$N1 = $_SESSION['grafo']->getVectorV();`

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso al colocarlo asi se cae la pagina

Comment: al colocarlo como ??

Comment: $N1 = $_SESSION['grafo']['getVectorV']; o $N1 = $_SESSION['grafo']->getVectorV();

de esa manera, la pagina se queda en un bucle infinito de carga

Comment: entonces tiene otro problema con ti codigo y es de logica no creo que se pueda resolver con lo que muestras... la otra pregunta que te hice no me las has respondido... como pasas el dato de PHP a javascript

Comment: este es mi disrcod: ArcanisGK507#6629 si quieres podemos ver esto mas tarde dentro de 3 horas.

Comment: listo nos comunicamos dentro de 3 horas